# Is there a term for instances of letter sequences that aren't pronounced as a single sound?

Tags: terminology, pronunciation

We don't pronounce "th" in "pothead" as a single logical sound, or "ph" (as "f") in haphazard. They are consecutive letters pronounced individually.

Is there a term to describe such a language phenomenon? I'm guessing no but it can lead to some humorous situations (I think on the Simpsons, policeman Lou said "poth-ead" which I found entertaining).

Comment: The vagaries of English spelling have nothing to do with the English language or its pronunciation, so there is no technical term. But you can make a game out of it if there's enough words to make a good list.

Comment: Hard vs. soft consonants? Silent vs. pronounced letters? "pothead" is two words that have become combined (written together without a space), so the letters would not ever be pronounced together as "th".

Comment: There was a kid at school who gained the nickname of 'meeth' for his entire school life because he once read out loud 'meeth-eed' instead of meathead. There's a similar game where you read things as if they were Italian [or French], so the trucking company Parceline becomes 'parch-el-eeni'.

Comment: @Tetsujin And I recently heard that it's becoming popular to pronounce "meme" as "me-me". If you combine that with Italianization, you get "may-may"

Comment: I don't think there's a term for this, since it's the normal way to pronounce letter sequences. There's a word for when a sequence of letters *is* combined into a new sound: dipthong.

Comment: Native speakers recognize that the word "pothead" consists of two components., "pot" and  "head".  Now that reading skill does have name, lexeme decomposition.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2504734/  A pothead might really enjoy that article.

Comment: @Barmar Diphthongs are two vowels joined together like _/ai/_ in _like_ /laik/. Two consonants joined together are called a "consonant cluster" But that's only for real (spoken, audible) vowels and consonants. Spelling just doesn't count for anything; like German noun genders and plural suffixes, English spelling has to be learned **in addition** to pronunciation.